# List counts 1 row data by using foreach

Tags: c#, list, split

```
var MyList= context.SP_List().ToList();
```

MyList contains 3 items.

- ProductID = "8,13,9"; CustomerName = "KochLtdCo"
- ProductID = "14,22,11"; CustomerName = "SabLtdCo"
- ProductID = "8,16,19"; CustomerName = "XxLtdCo"

I want to split ProductID  by comma after that. İf item.ProductID contains number "8" , ı want to add data(s) to list. I tried below but it did not work completely:

```
List<SP_List_Result> ResultList = new List<SP_List_Result>();

if(item.ProductID.toString()==8)
{
    ResultList.add(item);
    // this did not work because i have 2 rows data and it has only 1 row data(it counts 1 data)
}
```

How can i split by comma and add to list all datas?

Comment: You say that list counts (contains?) 2 data (items?), but provide 3 data. Also you haven't specified type of data

Comment: 2. data does not contain "8" number so , it must be count 2 data(1.data and 3. data) (Data includes  multiple columns , all of them string)

Comment: ProductID has type of string?

Comment: Yes Sergey , string (it has multiple ID'S) i split by comma after that i match (if ID=="8)etc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split by comma and project to integer ProductID property. That will give you collection if integers. Then simply use `Contains` to check if value `8` in that collection:

```
List<SP_List_Result> ResultList = new List<SP_List_Result>();

foreach (var item in MyList)
{
   var ids = item.ProductID.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse);
   if (ids.Contains(8))
       ResultList.Add(item);
}
```

Or even without foreach:

```
var query = from item in MyList
            let ids = item.ProductID.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse)
            where ids.Contains(8)
            select item;

ResultList = query.ToList();
```

Note: use camelCase names for local variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If you have skype please add me "SonerSevinc92" , i always open questions in stackoverflow , i can tell you from skype if you want to help me.

Comment: @user3156371 just write question on StackOverflow and somebody will help you :) The better you would describe your problem, the faster you will get help

Answer (score 0):

I thing this is you are looking

static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        List<Products> products = new List<Products>();

        List<Products> filtterdList=new List<Products>();
        products.Add(new Products { ProductID = "8, 13, 9", CustomerName = "KochLtdCo" });
        products.Add(new Products { ProductID = "89, 13, 9", CustomerName = "KochLtdCo" });

        string searchString = "8";
        filtterdList = products.Where(x=>SplitNumber(x.ProductID,8)).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(filtterdList.Count);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

  static  bool SplitNumber(string numbers,int numbertoFine)
    {
        int[] productId = numbers.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

        return productId.Any(x => x == numbertoFine);
    }
```

Comment: This will also match 78, which I guess is not desired.

Comment: @CarlR, check new solution  numberToFined*

Comment: Most simplified    string searchString = "8";
            filtterdList = products.Where(x=>x.ProductID.Split(',').Any(y=>y==searchString)).ToList();

Comment: Better :)
The "Most simplified" version looks like it will fail where there's a whitespace character with the 8.

Comment: @CarlR R  , i dont have much time to test my code so sorry for repeating my code , i am also working .. i think this will solve that issue   products.Where(x=>x.ProductID.Split(',').Any(y=>y.Trim()==searchString)).ToList();